\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-} does not work for LuaLatex Compiler
I am on overleaf where I can switch the compiler that I use. I am working on a poster and require the use of LuaLatex as a compiler. However, the line "\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}" causes "undefined control sequence" error.
I will give an example to illustrate my point.
\documentclass[pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Example}
    The equation is
    \begin{equation}
    y=mx+c
    \end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

It compiles fine when I choose the "pdfLatex" compiler but breaks when I use the "LuaLatex" compiler. Is there an alternative line (to \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}) that I can use for the LuaLatex compiler? Thanks.

For LuaLaTeX, don't load the inputenc and fontenc packages; instead, load the fontspec package.

@MIcro, thanks. So just replace the line \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} with \usepackage[utf8]{fontspec}? I tried it but still doesn't work. Can you show me the changes to my code above? You can type it as an answer and I can accept it.

DeclareUnicodeCharacter sets up inputenc to map the byte seqence for 2212  it is not defined for luatex you can just use the character  − directly

Please see the answer I posted. By the way, utf8 has been the default option for the inputenc package for several years now. (BTW, it's "Mico", not "Micro"...)

Somewhat related math mode - Why are minus signs not working in this equation? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange

I suggest you modify your preamble so that you can potentially compile the document with either pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.
\documentclass[pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage{iftex} % for '\iftutex' and related conditionals
\iftutex
   \usepackage{fontspec} % optional
\else
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   %\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % 'utf8' is the default nowadays
   \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}
   \usepackage{upgreek}
\fi

\usepackage{mathtools} % no need to load 'amsmath' separately

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Example}
    The equation is
    \begin{equation}
    y=mx-c
    \end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

With this setup, the inputenc and fontenc packages are loaded only if pdfLaTeX is used to compile the document.
Aside: Since the mathtools package loads amsmath automatically, there's no need to load amsmath separately. (And, with the beamer class, amsmath package is loaded by default...)

might be better to use \iftutex  rather than \ifpdflatex then latex and ptex as well as pdflatex would take the right branch

@DavidCarlisle - Great idea. :-) Let me fix that right away.

You can use the newunicodechar package in any engine:
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{−}{-} % U+2212

However, if you want to use Unicode input in LuaLaTeX, you are probably better off loading unicode-math with the professionalfonts option of beamer.

you can use newunicodechar  in any engine but not ^^^^  so a cross engine version would be \newunicodechar{−}{-}

@DavidCarlisle Good point. Edited.
